# Incorrect Long/Lat Plotting with ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, maps

```
dat <- read.table(text=" 'Country_of_Asylum' 'ISO_3' 'Refugees_1000_inhabitants' Lat Long
    Lebanon LBN   208.91 33.8333  35.8333
    Jordan  JOR    89.55 31.0000  36.0000
    Nauru   NRU   50.60 -0.5333 166.9167
    Chad   TCD    30.97 15.0000  19.0000
    Turkey   TUR  23.72 39.0000  35.0000
    'South Sudan'   SSD 22.32  4.8500  31.6000
    Mauritania   MRT  19.36 20.0000 -12.0000
    Djibouti   DJI    16.88 11.5000  43.0000 Sweden   SWE  14.66 62.0000  15.0000 Malta   MLT  14.58 35.9000  14.4000", header=TRUE)

data.frame(top_ten_pcapita)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
mdat <- map_data('world')
str(mdat)
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(dat=mdat, aes(long, lat, group=group), fill="grey50") +
  geom_point(data=top_ten_pcapita, 
             aes(x=Lat, y=Long, map_id=ISO_3, size=`Refugees_1000_inhabitants`), col="red")
```

I tried to make a map on ggplot, but the longitudes and latitudes are completely off.  I'm not entirely sure what's going on. For example, why is the lat. going over 100 on the map?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up longitude and latitude. If you added labels to your points you'd see that none of the countries is plotted at the correct place.

So make sure that x = Longitude and y = Latitude and it'll work:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(dat = mdat, aes(long, lat, group = group), fill = "grey50") +
  geom_point(data = top_ten_pcapita, 
             aes(x = long, y = lat, size = Refugees_1000_inhabitants), col = "red")
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, and yesterday was a three-cup-of-coffee kinda of day. Thanks, beetroot and Jeroen!

Answer (score 0):

You switched the x and y axis. x should be longitude, y should be latitude. Also, I don't think Nauru should have a negative longitude.

Try this:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(dat=mdat, aes(long, lat, group=group), fill="grey50") +
  geom_point(data=top_ten_pcapita, 
             aes(x=Long, y=Lat, size=`Refugees_1000_inhabitants`), col="red")
```